# Access elements in a vector of pointers to multi-dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm writing a program that allows tetris-like shapes to be input. I store these shapes in a 2-D vector of booleans so they'll then look like:

```
110   |   1   |   111
011   |   1   |   010
      |   1   |   111
// Where a 0 denotes "empty space"
```

I then point to each of those 2-D vectors and store those pointers in a vector called shapes.
My problem rests in accessing those individual 0's and 1's (in order to compare them to other shapes).

For example, given:

```
vector<vector<bool> > Shape;
vector<Shape *> shapes;
```

where shapes has three elements that point to the 2-D vectors I gave previously, I want to be able to access the 1 in the (0, 1) position of the first shape.

I've tried:

```
shapes[index]->at(0).at(1);
shapes[index]->at(0)[1];
shapes[index][0][1];
```

among many other things but none of these seem to be giving me what I want. I'm still fairly new to pointers so I hope I'm not just missing something blatantly obvious.

Thank you in advance!

As per request, here is a bigger chunk of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<vector<bool> > Shape;

class ShapeShifter {
public:
    ShapeShifter(int argc, char **argv);
    void Apply(int index, int row, int col);
    bool FindSolution(int index);
    void AddShape(Shape *newShape);
    void AddMove(int index, int row, int col);
    void PrintMoves();
    void PrintGrid();
protected:
    vector<vector<bool> > grid;
    vector<Shape *> shapes;
    vector<string> moves;
};

void ShapeShifter::Apply(int index, int row, int col) {
    int i, j, k;
    int y = 0, z = 0;

    if((row + shapes[index]->size() > grid.size()) || (col + shapes[index]->at(0).size() > grid[0].size())) {
        return; // shape won't fit
    }

    for(i = row; i < (row + shapes[index]->size()); i++) {
        for(j = col; j < (col + shapes[index]->at(0).size()); j++) {
            if(shapes[index]->at(y)[z] == 1) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 0) {
                    grid[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    grid[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }
            z++;
        }
        z = 0;
        y++;
    }
    return;
}
```

In this I have a grid of bools and I'm trying to mask it with the shape in the given index, where if the shape has a 1 the bool in the corresponding element of the grid will be flipped.

The shapes vector is populated with lines on standard input like so:

```
ShapeShifter sshift(argc, argv);
Shape *newShape;
vector<bool> shapeLine;
int i, j;
string line;

while(getline(cin, line)) {
    j = 0;
    newShape = new Shape;
    for(i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
        if(line[i] == ' ') {
            j++;
        }
        else {
            shapeLine.push_back(line[i] - '0');
        }
    }
    newShape->push_back(shapeLine);
    sshift.AddShape(newShape);
    line.clear();
}

void ShapeShifter::AddShape(Shape *newShape) {
    shapes.push_back(newShape);
}
```

Comment: What does `giving me what I want` mean? What are you expecting? What do you get?

Comment: Posting bits and pieces of code is not helpful. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What values are you getting when you evaluate the three expressions that you posted at the end.

Comment: @Ben I'd like it to return the 1 so I can then compare it with another boolean to see if they are the same/etc. Something like if(shapes[index]->at(0).at(1) == 1) {do this}

Comment: `'1'` as not the same thing as `1`. Start by understanding this simple concept.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik He just said "return the 1", clearly he meant the char '1' from the string in question

Comment: @Toy_Reid It would be helpful if you could upload more information. In particular, the results of what you've tried and how you're actually populating `shapes`

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, I realize I should have done that. I've updated the original post.

Comment: @Toy_Reid That `if / else` statement that changes the grid value could be re[laced with simply `if(shapes[index]->at(y)[z]) grid[i][j] = !grid[i][j];`.  Also, why do you need to use pointers in your program?  I don't see a need for them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My professor is fairly adamant about using pointers whenever you're storing vectors, but my solution might just be to do away with them. Good point about the if statement, I was trying to figure out how to do it along those lines but I was up pretty late last night haha.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a vector of `string` and not just a 2D array of char or whatever you need? Then you could access them easily: `shape[x][y]`.

Anyway, the way you currently have it set up you can access the value you want like this:
`shapes[0]->at(0).at(1);`

Comment: This will not work as `shapes[0]` evaluates to a pointer. You have to dereference it to access the `vector<string>`.

Comment: Woops, didn't see he used `Shape *`, gotta change to `->`

Comment: I accidentally included the wrong typedef, it should actually be a vector<vector<bool> >, not a vector<string>.

Comment: @Toy_Reid yeah I suspect the problem actually lies with how you populated the vector, as something like `shapes[0]->at(0)[1]` should work.

Comment: @EricM. I've updated the post with information on how the vector is populated.